# Save a view/Layout to file. Is it possible?

Tags: android, file, android-layout, view

I have an app, with many views, which have ImageViews and TextView etc. in them. They have to be exact the same with every app launch, so when the user exits, I save the data from the imageViews to a file (the path to the image), and I have to generate the textViews again, which is a long process. The app works perfectly, but a little slow. So my question is: Is it possible to save a View/Layout (eg. RelativeLayout), with everything in it (childs, and there childs) in a file. Somehow compressed maybe, and decompress when opened. That way some things that take long to programmatically generate every time, are going to be just read from a file. The process is supposedly going to take a lot less time. Any ideas? Maybe in future APIs?

Comment: i guess the proper way to do this would be to save the state of all the views in SharedPreferences...

Comment: have you considered using a database?

Comment: Can you save View/Layout and its children intact in a DB? Eg if I have loaded image in ImageView, it will be saved too, with the ImageView, and then be loaded in the exact same way. Can that be done using a DB?